# mouse event that keeps running when pressing mouse key

Tags: javafx

I'm working on a custom scroll bar that moves when I press and hold the primary mouse key. I tried setOnMousePressed, but this only runs one time. Is there an event that keeps running when I'm holding down a key? 
Edit: I should have mentioned the custom scroll bar is actually a normal pane where I display a bigger range of the graph I show in the scroll pane.

Comment: You could trigger a `while` loop when the mouse is pressed down and set the variable which is true to false when the user releases the mouse.

Comment: Have a look on [this event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_DRAGGED).

Comment: hmm ... scrolling as long as the primary mouse button is pressed is the default behaviour ..

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Never use a "endless" loop in an event-handler like `onMousePressed` since this will freeze the UI.

Comment: then have a look on how the normal scrollbar implements it and do the same with your custom control

Comment: Take a look at [JavaFX: Working with Event Filters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/filters.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is the default behavior for a scroll bar. However, if you want to implement something like this yourself, for some reason, one option is to use an `AnimationTimer` in conjunction with mouse listeners:

```
AnimationTimer scrollDownTimer = new AnimationTimer() {

    long lastMoveTime = -1 ;

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        if (lastMoveTime > 0) {
            long elapsedNanos = now-lastMoveTime ;
            // scroll down amount based on time elapsed...
        }
        lastMoveTime = now ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        lastMoveTime = -1 ;
        super.start();
    }
};
```

And now just

```
scrollDownButton.setOnMousePressed(e -> scrollDownTimer.start());
scrollDownButton.setOnMouseReleased(e -> scrollDownTimer.stop());
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollingExample extends Application {

    private Rectangle rect ;
    private Pane rectPane ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        rect = new Rectangle(0, 200, 40, 40);
        rect.setFill(Color.CORAL);

        Label left = new Label("Left");
        Label right = new Label("Right");

        ScrollTimer scrollTimer = new ScrollTimer(); 

        left.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            scrollTimer.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
            scrollTimer.start();
        });

        left.setOnMouseReleased(e -> scrollTimer.stop());

        right.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            scrollTimer.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
            scrollTimer.start();
        });

        right.setOnMouseReleased(e -> scrollTimer.stop());

        AnchorPane buttons = new AnchorPane(left, right);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(left, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(right, 5.0);

        rectPane = new Pane(rect);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(rectPane);
        root.setTop(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public enum Direction { 
        LEFT(-1), RIGHT(1) ; 
        private int multiplier ;

        Direction(int multiplier) {
            this.multiplier = multiplier ;
        }

        public double multiply(double value) {
            return value * multiplier ;
        }
    }

    public  class ScrollTimer extends AnimationTimer {
        private double speed = 250 ; // pixels/second

        private Direction direction = Direction.LEFT ;

        private long lastUpdate ;

        @Override
        public void start() {
            lastUpdate = -1 ;
            super.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {

            if (lastUpdate < 0) {
                lastUpdate = now ;
                return ;
            }

            long elapsedNanos = now - lastUpdate ;

            double elapsedSeconds = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000_000.0 ;
            double deltaX = elapsedSeconds * direction.multiply(speed);


            rect.setX(clamp(rect.getX() + deltaX, 0, rectPane.getWidth() - rect.getWidth()));

            lastUpdate = now ;
        }

        private double clamp(double value, double min, double max) {
            if (value < min) return min ;
            if (value > max) return max ;
            return value ;
        }

        public void setDirection(Direction direction) {
            this.direction = direction ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your scroll bar a on drag method that would be easier to achieve

Comment: easier: yes, but not what I have to implement. Adding a drag event would mean the user has to move the mouse to scroll, but what I want to do is that he can press onto the scrollbar to scroll. Furthermore the scrolling speed depends on the position he's pressing the button (near the middle of the pane: slow scrolling, at the ends of the pane: fast scrolling).